# Recursive function not working as expected php

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion

I have ebay categories that have `parent_id`s.  The top level category doesn't have a `parent_id`.  I am trying to write a recursive function that will return me an array from lowest category to highest e.g.:

```
array
    0 => string '27"' 
    1 => string 'Monitors' 
    2 => string 'TV, Monitors and Display'
```

So far, however, it's causing an infinite loop.  I think it's because the `parent_id` isn't being passed when the function is called again, it's using the `$ebay_store_category_id` from what was passed the first time the function was called rather than `parent_id`.

```
public static function get_ebay_cats($ebay_store_category) {
    $cat_array = array();
    $ebay_store_category_id = $ebay_store_category->category_id;
    $array = self::get_cat_array($ebay_store_category_id, $cat_array);
}

private function get_cat_array($ebay_store_category_id, &$cat_array, ) {
    $ebay_cat_model = new Ebay_store_category_model($ebay_store_category_id);
    $ebay_cat_model->get();
    $cat_array[$ebay_cat_model->category_id] = $ebay_cat_model->name;
    $parent_id = $ebay_cat_model->parent_id;
    echo 'parent id :'.$parent_id.' | current category id: '.$ebay_cat_model->category_id.'<br/>';

    if(!empty($parent_id)) {
        return self::get_cat_array($parent_id, $cat_array);
    }

    return $cat_array;
}
```

**The results of the echo**

*How I know its infinite and the parent id is not being passed when the function references itself:*

`parent id :6692320015 | current category id: 6697237015
 parent id :6692320015 | current category id: 6697237015
 parent id :6692320015 | current category id: 6697237015
 parent id :6692320015 | current category id: 6697237015
 parent id :6692320015 | current category id: 6697237015`

My table structure:

```
+------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id         | parent_id  | name                          | order | category_id |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| 7          | NULL       | TV, Monitors and Displays     |     0 | 7           |
| 6701115015 | 7          | Monitors                      |     4 | 6701115015  |
| 5661200015 | 6701115015 | 27"                           |     3 | 6701114015  |
```

Comment: BTW: You are passing `$count` in to `get_cat_array` which is never read.

Comment: thanks, taken it out.  Was using it in my code, thought I had taken them all out for readability.

Comment: If there is infinite loop, the condition is probably true in all cases. I would print out the `$parent_id` for debugging to see why it's not empty.

Comment: I've included my echo statement I was using and the results, its always the same `$parent_id`

Comment: looks like its a weird code ignitor thing.  I tried getting the model using get_where and it now works as expected :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a CI thing.  I used `$ebay_cat_model->get_where(array('id'=>$ebay_store_category_id));` instead of `$ebay_cat_model = new Ebay_store_category_model($ebay_store_category_id);` and it works now.